# Need SlimDX to display images quickly

Tags: c#, image, latency, slimdx

I need to display images very quickly (about 60 FPS).  Picturebox/Panel doesn't do the job at higher resolutions, so I am now turning to SlimDX, which I hope is the right move.

As SlimDX uses Directx, and DirectX uses the GPU, I should be able to do it very quickly.  From my understanding, the GPU works with images a lot faster than with the CPU.

I am doing this:

```
MessagePump.Run(form, () =>
{
    device.BeginScene();
    sprite.Begin(SlimDX.Direct3D9.SpriteFlags.None);
    tx = SlimDX.Direct3D9.Texture.FromStream(device, (new MemoryStream(reader.ReadBytes(reader.ReadInt32()))), SlimDX.Direct3D9.Usage.None, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Pool.Managed);
    sprite.Draw(tx, Color.Transparent);

    sprite.End();
    device.EndScene();
    device.Present();
});
```

And initializing everything:

```
var form = new RenderForm("Test");
form.Width = 1280;
form.Height = 720;
SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentParameters presentParams = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentParameters
{
 BackBufferWidth = form.Width,
 BackBufferHeight = form.Height,
 DeviceWindowHandle = form.Handle,
 PresentFlags = SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentFlags.None,
 BackBufferCount = 0,
 PresentationInterval = SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentInterval.Immediate,
 SwapEffect = SlimDX.Direct3D9.SwapEffect.Discard,
 BackBufferFormat = SlimDX.Direct3D9.Format.A8R8G8B8,
 Windowed = true,
};

device = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device(new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Direct3D(), 0, SlimDX.Direct3D9.DeviceType.Hardware, form.Handle, SlimDX.Direct3D9.CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, presentParams);
device.Viewport = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Viewport(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height);
    SlimDX.Direct3D9.Sprite sprite;
    SlimDX.Direct3D9.Texture tx;
    sprite = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Sprite(device);
    tx = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Texture(device, form.Width, form.Height, 0, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Usage.None, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Format.X8R8G8B8, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Pool.Managed);
```

There are two problems with this:

1. it's extremely slow; picturebox is much faster
2. it shows the image incorrectly (it's zoomed in)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache the textures, as making them every frame is slow. E.g.

public class CacheObjects
{
    static List cacheSCBrushes = new List();

```
public static SolidColorBrush GetColorBrush(Color4 Color, Direct2D.RenderTarget renderTGT)
{
     // ERROR: Not supported in C#: OnErrorStatement

    SolidColorBrush returnBrush = null;
    bool found = false;
    foreach (void br_loopVariable in cacheSCBrushes) {
        br = br_loopVariable;
        if (br.Color.Red == Color.Red) {
            if (br.Color.Green == Color.Green) {
                if (br.Color.Blue == Color.Blue) {
                    if (br.Color.Alpha == Color.Alpha) {
                        found = true;
                        returnBrush = br;
                        exit for;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        returnBrush = new SolidColorBrush(renderTGT, Color);
        cacheSCBrushes.Add(returnBrush);
    }
    return returnBrush;
}


public static void ClearCache()
{
    foreach (void Brush_loopVariable in cacheSCBrushes) {
        Brush = Brush_loopVariable;
        Brush.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

If that is impossible, [In a seperate thread], load the next 5 textures...Rendering is fast, object creation is slow.

```
public void LoadTexture () {
//Load the next 5 here
}
```